# Microsoft Defender for Containers - Number of container vulnerabilities differs heavily between trivy and Microsoft Defender Vulnerability Management

Tags: azure, security, containers, trivy, azure-defender

I am currently working on a POC for checking vulnerabilities in existing container images stored in azure container registries (Microsoft Defender for Cloud enabled). While the integrated azure "Microsoft Defender Vulnerability Management"-solution finds only 41, trivy identifies 224 vulnerabilities for the exact same image. For basically every image in my ACR, there is a huge difference in findings between both scan solutions. There a some overlaps in terms of CVEs found with the same severity, but it seems like, that trivy is just scanning much more CVEs and has more databases available.

I couldn't find out, if both scans are using different CVE-database sources. Does anybody know or has resources to dive a little bit deeper?

Comment: Yes they are both using different database sources

Comment: Hey @Arko, thanks for your quick answer! Do you have any sources to read a little bit further?

Comment: yeah sure, I'll post it as answer, won't fit in comments

Comment: Microsoft Defender is still in 'it's early days when we talk about container security . A lot of open source packages and commercial offerings like Snyk are very mature in area , please do explore them out as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Trivy](https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.40/docs/vulnerability/db/) and [Microsoft Defender Vulnerability Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/agentless-vulnerability-assessment-azure) use different vulnerability databases and scanning methods, which can result in different numbers of identified vulnerabilities for the same image.

Trivy is an open-source scanner that uses multiple vulnerability databases, including the National Vulnerability Database (NVD) and [Red Hat's vulnerability database](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-25/product_id-78/Redhat-Enterprise-Linux.html). On the other hand, Microsoft Defender Vulnerability Management uses its own vulnerability database and scanning methods. It is possible that Trivy is identifying more vulnerabilities because it has access to a larger number of vulnerability databases. However, it is also important to note that different scanners may have different definitions of what constitutes a vulnerability, which can also contribute to differences in identified vulnerabilities.

For example, Trivy maintains a vulnerability database that is updated every six hours
[image]
and includes information from a variety of sources. On the other hand, Microsoft Defender Vulnerability Management is designed to integrate tightly with Azure services and may use a different set of criteria for scanning and identifying vulnerabilities.

References:

- [Vulnerability assessments for Azure with Microsoft Defender Vulnerability Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/agentless-vulnerability-assessment-azure)
- [Overview of Container security in Microsoft Defender for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-containers-introduction#vulnerability-assessment)
- [How does image scanning work?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/agentless-vulnerability-assessment-azure#how-does-image-scanning-work)
- [Trivi's vulnerability database](https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.40/docs/vulnerability/db/)